# How to allow multiple Hyphen in action method name in mvc core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-core-3.1

I am working on an application in which requirements are to show url in following format for seo.

```
Initial format = www.abc.com/Home/OnlineShoppingInUk

Required format = www.abc.com/online-shopping-in-uk
```

I have done following changes in start.cs to hide controller name from url and controller name is removed from url

```
     endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "onlineShoppingInUk",
                    pattern: "onlineShoppingInUk",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "onlineShoppingInUk" });

and in home controller

     [Route("onlineShoppingInUk")]
     public IActionResult OnlineShoppingInUk()
    {
    ....
    }
```

But above method not works when url contains hyphen. I have tried following but online-shopping action method never calls and instead index method is called.

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "online-shopping-in-uk",
                    pattern: "online-shopping-in-uk",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "online-shopping-in-uk" });
```

and in home controller

```
     [Route("online-shopping-in-uk")]
     public IActionResult OnlineShoppingInUk()
    {
    ....
    }
```

How to call an action method containing hyphens in Home controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your route config with below code.

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "OnlineShoppingInUK",
                pattern: "/online-shopping-in-uk",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "OnlineShoppingInUK" });
```

Remove Route from your method :

```
public IActionResult OnlineShoppingInUK()
    {
    ....
    }
```

And try this :

```
www.abc.com/online-shopping-in-uk
```

Also where your are calling this just use

> asp-route="OnlineShoppingInUK"

Comment: actually url contains more then one hyphen in action method name.

Comment: method is not calling instead default index method is called

Comment: If it's contains more than one hyphen then also it should work